# Compilation Error with JModelica on macOS: Missing libblas_OPENMP.a File

Tags: macos, makefile, compiler-errors, blas, jmodelica

I'm trying to compile [JModelica](https://github.com/JModelica/JModelica) on my macOS system, but I'm running into a problem during the make process, specifically when it attempts to compile the BLAS library as part of the SuperLU package. Here's the error message I received:

```
ar cr ../lib/libblas_OPENMP.a isamax.o sasum.o saxpy.o scopy.o sdot.o snrm2.o srot.o sscal.o \
sgemv.o ssymv.o strsv.o sger.o ssyr2.o
ar: ../lib/libblas_OPENMP.a: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [single] Error 1
make[3]: *** [blaslib] Error 2
make[2]: *** [all-local] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The make process appears unable to find or create the `libblas_OPENMP.a` file in the expected directory. I've checked that the `CBLAS/` directory contains the necessary BLAS routines and that the makefiles are set up to compile these into the `libblas_OPENMP.a` library. According to the documentation, this library should be compiled from the sources in the `CBLAS/` subdirectory of SuperLU_MT, but the process fails with the above error.

I have reviewed the README, `make.inc`, and the relevant `Makefile.am` and `Makefile` in the `CBLAS` directory to ensure the setup is correct for compiling the BLAS library, but the issue persists.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or does anyone have any insights on how to resolve this? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or fix this error.

**System Information:**

- macOS version: 12.7.3
- Compiler version:

  - GCC Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
  - Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
  - Thread model: posix
  - InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Useful light would be shed on your problem if you 1) run `make distclean` in the
package build dir, 2) rerun your `./configure ...` command, 3) show that command in full in your post, and the full path where you run it, and any warnings that it emits, 4) run `make` in the package build dir and show in your post the output beginning with the last `make[N]: Entering directory ....` message that precedes the failure right up until the failed build terminates.

Comment: @MikeKinghan The `Makefile` doesn't have any `distclean`/`clean` targets!

Comment: Just cloned the repo https://github.com/JModelica/JModelica.git.
Can `$ ./configure ...`; `$ make`, `$ make clean`, `$ make distclean`.
Any `make` target is only available between a successful `$ ./configure ...` and next `$ make distclean`, so your repo now seems to be in an pre-configured/post-distclean state. My build also fails but much later than yours (in ThirdParty/Sundials). 
The `ar cr ../lib/libblas_OPENMP.a isamax.o sasum.o saxpy.o scopy.o sdot.o snrm2.o srot.o  ...` that fails for you succeeds for me, early in the build. Can't help more except as per previous comments.